# Trimming fields with a recursive function doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to trim fields of a form before submitting, but for some reason, the values are left untouched. The recursive function is defined as:

```
const trimFields = form => _.forIn(form, element => isObject(element) ? trimFields(element) : trimText(element))
```

But this doesn't work at all, it just seems to keep the original value.

What am I doing wrong here?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vuzL4dc/)

Comment: I can't see function call trimFields in you fiddle

Comment: Here's with minor tweaks it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/j0r9v5wt/

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive function never actually modifies the `form` or returns something of use. You need to modify your object's keys when you meet a value with a string (or non-object). If you meet a value with an object, you can call your function again to trim its values.

```
const trimFields = form => _.forIn(form, (element, k) => {
  if(_.isObject(element)) {
    trimFields(element)
  } else {
    form[k] = _.trim(element); // set the object's key to be the trimmed version of its element
  } 
});

trimFields(form);
// set the values of the elements...
```

The above doesn't require lodash methods though, and you can use standard inbuilt structures to perform what you're after.

With that being said, I suggest you use [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapValues) to produce a new form object instead of modifying your current form object. This works by returning the new value the object should take. If the `element` is an object, you can make rerun your function recursively on it to map the `element`s objects. If it's not an object, you can use lodash's [`_.trim()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#trim) method to return the trimmed value for that current object value.

```
const trimFields = form => _.mapValues(form, 
  element => _.isObject(element) ? trimFields(element) : _.trim(element)
);
```

See example below:

```js
const form = {name: '   John Doe   ', email: 'john@doe.com', handle: 'jdoe', social: { facebook: '    John Doe\'s page', twitter: '@jdoe'}};

const trimFields = form => _.mapValues(form, 
  element => _.isObject(element) ? trimFields(element) : _.trim(element)
);

const new_form = trimFields(form);
document.getElementById('name').value = new_form.name;
document.getElementById('email').value = new_form.email;
document.getElementById('handle').value = new_form.handle;
document.getElementById('facebook').value = new_form.social.facebook;
document.getElementById('twitter').value = new_form.social.twitter;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="email" id="email" />
  <input type="text" id="handle" />
  <input type="text" id="facebook" />
  <input type="text" id="twitter" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in the fiddle provided you:

1. never actually trigger `trimFields`. trimFields(form) is missing.
2. populate the inputs with the data in `form`. The values that you intend to trim are never used to populate your form fields. In other words, you are not mutating your original `form` object.